# Linq in C# using IEnumerable

Tags: linq

Appearently, I got an error if using the following code. It said:

> Cannot implicity converrt type `System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType>` to `System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable`.

Please advise how I can fix this?

```
public IEnumerable<Session> GetAllListDetailConsumer(string refId)
{
    ObjectQuery<Session> sessions = db.Sessions;
    ObjectQuery<SessionsList> sessionsLists = db.SessionsList;
    var query =
        from s in sessions
        join sList in sessionsLists on s.ReferralListID equals sList.ReferralListID
        where s.ReferralListID == new Guid(refId)
        select new SessionConsumerList
        {
            ReferralListID = s.ReferralListID,
            SessionServerId = s.SessionServerID,
            ApplicationID = s.ApplicationID,
            // ...
            ConsumerID = sList.ConsumerID,
            ConsumerFirstName = sList.ConsumerFirstName,
            ConsumerFamilyName = sList.ConsumerFamilyName,
            // ...
        };
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not separate the creation of the `SessionConsumerList` in another method? Makes the code a lot cleaner. Like this:

```
public static SessionConsumerList CreateSessionConsumerList(
    Session s,
    SessionsList sList)
{
    return new SessionConsumerList
    {
        ReferralListID = s.ReferralListID,
        SessionServerId = s.SessionServerID,
        ApplicationID = s.ApplicationID,
        // ...
        ConsumerID = sList.ConsumerID,
        ConsumerFirstName = sList.ConsumerFirstName,
        ConsumerFamilyName = sList.ConsumerFamilyName,
        // ...
    };
}
```

And then:

```
var query =
    from s in sessions
    join sList in sessionsLists on s.ReferralListID equals sList.ReferralListID
    where s.ReferralListID == new Guid(refId)
    select CreateSessionConsumerList(s, sList);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting using `select new`, which would create an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx), you need to project to class `Session` in your query like.

```
select new Session
{
....
```

But remember if your `Session` class is a representing a table in your database/data context, then you can't project to that class, instead you may have to create a temporary class and project the selection to that class.

**EDIT** *(Since the question now has been edited)*

Now you are selecting `new SessionConsumerList` and you are returning `IEnumerable<Session>`, you need to modify method signature to return `IEnumerable<SessionConsumerList>`

Comment: i already add temporary class. but i need to return query and i could not return as query.ToList()

Comment: @Supermode, check the edited part of the answer, You need to modify the method signature...